# VS2012 Express for web - FluentMigrator.Tools 1.0.3.0 - where is the migrate.exe?

Tags: nuget-package, fluent-migrator

I'm using VS Express for Web. I've added FluentMigrator.Tools 1.0.3.0 to the project. Where should I see the Migrate.exe? I've been looking for that inside bin/Debug (after I built the project), but it is nowhere.

Other dll-s included in the FluentMigrator.Tools package are also missing from the References of the project.

Am I missing something? Where can I find that migrate.exe?

Ok, I know that I can get it from the Nuget\Cache but I would suspect, that these tools will be attached to my project, after a build I can find them in the bin/Debug or Release folder, and I can ship them with binaries.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, never mind, I see that those files can be found under the `SolutionRoot\packages\FluentMigrator.Tools.`*version*`\tools\...` folders.

Comment: I just went through this myself and one thing I found helpful was copying this to my output directory at each build so I could find it where my migration DLL is. I use the following as a post-build command (mind the quotes!): `powershell -command "copy-item -Force -Recurse (((Get-ChildItem -Path '$(ProjectPath)\..\..\packages' -Filter FluentMigrator.Tools.* | Sort-Object -Descending LastWriteTime)[0].FullName)  + '\tools\') '$(TargetDir)'"`